# How to remove Gekodriver from Path

Tags: command-line, bash

I am new to Ubuntu (Ubuntu Mate) and wanted to continue coding.
I reached a site which had many links an I had to click all so I made a *Bot*, for that I installed **GekoDriver** after I was done I wanted to delete **GekoDriver** so I selected it then clicked shift + del to permanently delete it and the .deb installer.

After that when I checked my Path it showed the following result:

```bsh
root@root:~$ $PATH
```

bash: /home/tony/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin: **No such file or directory**

So how do I remove it ??

Comment: You are trying to execute $PATH... if you wish to print the content of a variable use `echo $PATH`

Comment: How to remove **"No such file or directory"**. When I try echo $PATH it doesn't show     " No such file or directory ".

Comment: ![screenshot.jpg](https://ibb.co/87fbg3B)